# How to get the dynamical text using substring

Tags: java, string

I have a text like `"Bus is from bangalore to chennai on 02/11/2017"`. By using `substring` need to get the text of bangalore and chennai.

But these are dynamic, Sometimes this may vary like delhi or mumbai.

Comment: You need to extract city names??

Comment: You mean you want to get the cities from a string with this pattern "Bus is from [cityA] to [cityB] on [date]" ?

Comment: Please clarify more about your problem and post some code here what went wrong when you tried it.